# node sequelize sort by multiple columns

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Coming from a Ruby/Rails background, I'm used to this type of syntax:

`Model.all.order('col1 + col2 + col3')`

So, given that col1, col2 and col3 are integers, for example, it would sort the results by the sum of those 3 columns.

Is there a similar way to sort like this using sequelize?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the latest master (not sure if the change has been pushed to npm yet), you can do the following:

```
Model.findAll({ order: [[{ raw: 'col1 + col2 + col3 DESC' }]]});
```

Resulting in

```
ORDER BY col1 + col2 + col3 DESC
```

Or you can do:

```
Model.findAll({ order: [[sequelize.fn('SUM', sequelize.col('col1'), sequelize.col('col2'), sequelize.col('col3')), 'DESC']]});
```

Resulting in

```
ORDER BY SUM(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) DESC
```

I would recommend the second version, which will properly escape the column names. For more info see http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-finders-limit---offset---order---group

Answer (score 12):

```
order: [
   ['created_at', 'desc'],
   ['id', 'desc']
]
```

or

```
order: [
   [sequelize.literal('created_at, id'), 'desc']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to sort by a col1+col2 in my model's defaultScope, the SUM solution provided as answer returned a sequelize error `function sum(numeric, numeric) does not exists` (or something similar).

My current workaround :

```
order: [[ 'col1', sequelize.literal('+'), 'col2', 'DESC']]
```

which will print out

```
ORDER BY "tableName"."col1"+"col2" DESC
```

just add more interspaced columns and `sequelize.literal('+')` for more columns.

If using includes/joins and you need all columns to be called with the table name...  I tried `sequelize.col('col2')` but the table name wasn't added. I *guess* a combination like `'tableName', sequelize.literal('.'), 'columnName'` should work, but you need to know your tableName/alias. And I couldn't access my model since it was being defined in my use case. The `{model: 'model', as: 'alias'}` from the documentation failed too.